# Why wont this IF statement work in Unity?

Tags: if-statement, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Okay I have a problem. I am using an IF statement. It seems to not run like it should. It works fine without the || condition, but with the || it seems to just pull the text under and not run the ELSE...

```
var fateText : UI.Text;
var inputText : UI.Text;


 function fateBall () {
        if(inputText.text == "illuminati"||"Illuminati"){
            fateText.text = "We run the entire world. Join us!";
    }else{
  var myRandomString : String = RandomWordString(1);
 fateText.text = myRandomString;
   }
   }
```

If i remove the ||"Illuminati" it works great... but like this it assigns fateText.text to "We run the entire world." and not the myRandomString

EDIT REPORT: Okay, the .ToLower() worked great now I am running into a problem where when I add multiple IFs it just bypasses the IFs and just runs the ELSE... any ideas?

```
function fateBall () {
    if(inputText.text.ToLower() == "illuminati"){
            fateText.text = "We run the entire world. Join us!";}
     if(inputText.text.ToLower() == "satan"){
                fateText.text = "Lucifer is the Light Bringer. He leads us           against God!";}
     if(inputText.text.ToLower() == "devil"){
            fateText.text = "Lucifer is the Light Bringer. He leads us     against God!";}
    if(inputText.text.ToLower() == "lucifer"){
            fateText.text = "Lucifer is the Light Bringer. He leads us against God!";}

            else{
 var myRandomString : String = RandomWordString(1);
    fateText.text = myRandomString;
 }
 }
```

Comment: You should change the statement as, `if(inputText.text == "illuminati" || inputText.text =="Illuminati")` js basics. Also better use  === for exact comparison. If you want to do any other comparison in the same statement, do it like  `if( (inputText.text == "illuminati" || inputText.text =="Illuminati" ) || inputText.text == "blalabla" )`

Comment: I added ELSE IF. I tried that before but I had === instead of ==. Now it works perfectly! If anyone knows how to simplify this code by adding simular words like Lucifer, Satan, Devil in an array then using that array in one IF statement let me know! Thanks -- BTW im not a devil worshiper or nothing like that. Im creating a Magic 8 Ball game for fun... but the game is horror in nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition must be :

```
if(inputText.text == "illuminati" || inputText.text == "Illuminati")
```

Otherwise, you can set to lower all the text so as to be case-independant :

```
if(inputText.text.ToLower() == "illuminati")
```

An even better way to compare strings is to use the `Equals` function (**C# only though**)

```
if( String.Equals( inputText.text, "illuminati", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

---

EDIT further to your EDIT:

```
string lowerText = inputText.text.ToLower() ;

if(lowerText == "illuminati")
{
    fateText.text = "We run the entire world. Join us!";
}
else if(lowerText == "satan")
{
    fateText.text = "Lucifer is the Light Bringer. He leads us           against God!";
}
else if(lowerText == "devil")
{
    fateText.text = "Lucifer is the Light Bringer. He leads us     against God!";
}
else if(lowerText == "lucifer")
{
    fateText.text = "Lucifer is the Light Bringer. He leads us against God!";
}
else
{
    var myRandomString : String = RandomWordString(1);
    fateText.text = myRandomString;
}
```

Comment: Okay, the .ToLower() worked great now I am running into a problem where when I add multiple IFs it just bypasses the IFs and just runs the ELSE... any ideas?

Comment: @Matt Vapes : I've edited my answer further to the edit to your question

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the condition from:

```
inputText.text == "illuminati"||"Illuminati"
```

To this:

```
inputText.text == "illuminati"|| inputText.text =="Illuminati"
```

I don't think you can chain conditions like that.

In addition you may want to just use a lowercase function to simplify your condition. So I believe you can do the following instead.

```
if(inputText.text.ToLower()=="illuminati")
```

Comment: `ToLower()` and `ToLowercase()` do the same thing

Comment: Yep, no problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check multiple condidtions in one if statement do it like this:

```
if (var1 == condition1 || var2 == condition2){}
```

this will check if either one return true, but you can also check if multiple statements are true by using:

```
if (var1 == condition1 && var2 == condition2){}
```